# How Can I convert React.createclass to Class Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs, draggable

I have taken an example of dragging certain div in react js from here
http://jsfiddle.net/Af9Jt/2/

Now it is in createClass and I need to convert it into `class Draggable extends React.Component` in order to export it into another component. Here is  code

APP.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Draggable from './Draggable.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Draggable />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Draggable.js

```
import React from 'react';

export class Draggable extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pos: {x: 0, y: 0},
            dragging: false,
            rel: null
        };

        this.onMouseMove = this.onMouseMove.bind(this);
        this.onMouseDown = this.onMouseDown.bind(this);
        this.onMouseUp = this.onMouseUp.bind(this);
    }


    // we could get away with not having this (and just having the listeners on
    // our div), but then the experience would be possibly be janky. If there's
    // anything w/ a higher z-index that gets in the way, then you're toast,
    // etc.
    // componentDidUpdate(props, state) {
    //   if (this.state.dragging && !state.dragging) {
    //     document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove)
    //     document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp)
    //   } else if (!this.state.dragging && state.dragging) {
    //     document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove)
    //     document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp)
    //   }
    // }
  
    // calculate relative position to the mouse and set dragging=true
    onMouseDown(e) {
      console.log("1")
      console.log(this.state);
      if (e.button !== 0) return
      this.setState({
        dragging: true,
        rel: {
          x: e.pageX - e.nativeEvent.offsetX,
          y: e.pageY - e.nativeEvent.offsetY
        }
      })
      e.stopPropagation()
      e.preventDefault()
    }

    onMouseUp(e) {
      this.setState({dragging: false})
      e.stopPropagation()
      e.preventDefault()
    }

    onMouseMove(e) {
      if (!this.state.dragging) return
      this.setState({
        pos: {
          x: e.pageX - this.state.rel.x,
          y: e.pageY - this.state.rel.y
        }
      })
      e.stopPropagation()
      e.preventDefault()
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div 
            style={{position: "absolute", left: "175px", top: "65px", border: "2px solid rgb(170, 170, 85)", padding: "10px"}}
            className="my-draggable" data-reactid=".r[2zxee]" id="messi" 
            onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
            onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
            onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
            initialPos = {{x:0,y:0}}
            >
                Drag Me! See how children are passed through to the div!
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Draggable;
```

Everything runs fine in this code the box is shown but I cannot drag the div, I couldn't figure out what issue is this. How Can I Solve this?

Here is my sample code in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/6vdurk79/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few things I noticed when converting this into a React.Component:

1. You never used the `this.state.pos` when rendering, so even if the position changed in the variables, it wouldn't move the div. The `style` attribute of the `<div>` is just hard-coded with `{ left: "175px", top: "65px" }`
2. You didn't properly get the position of the mouse in your `this.onMouseDown` function, which caused it to forced every movement to be at the corner.
3. You never bound `this.onMouseMove` to anything. Uncommenting the big chunk of commented out code fixed this.
4. The `initialPos` attribute you place inside the `<div>` does absolutely nothing. I converted that into a prop in the constructor.

Here's the updated JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ogy4xd1c/3/

And I'll embed it here on StackOverflow in a snippet.

```js
class Draggable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pos: props.initialPos || {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      },
      dragging: false,
      rel: null
    }

    this.onMouseMove = this.onMouseMove.bind(this);
    this.onMouseDown = this.onMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.onMouseUp = this.onMouseUp.bind(this);
  }

  // calculate relative position to the mouse and set dragging=true
  onMouseDown(e) {
    if (e.button !== 0) return
    const de = document.documentElement;
    const box = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getBoundingClientRect();
    const top = box.top + window.pageYOffset - de.clientTop;
    const left = box.left + window.pageXOffset - de.clientLeft;
    this.setState({
      dragging: true,
      rel: {
        x: e.pageX - left,
        y: e.pageY - top,
      }
    })
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  onMouseUp(e) {
    this.setState({
      dragging: false
    })
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  onMouseMove(e) {
    if (!this.state.dragging) return
    this.setState({
      pos: {
        x: e.pageX - this.state.rel.x,
        y: e.pageY - this.state.rel.y
      }
    })
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  componentDidUpdate(props, state) {
    if (this.state.dragging && !state.dragging) {
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove)
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp)
    } else if (!this.state.dragging && state.dragging) {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove)
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return ( <div
      style={{
            position: "absolute",
            left: this.state.pos.x,
            top: this.state.pos.y,
            border: "2px solid rgb(170, 170, 85)",
            padding: "10px"
        }}
        className="my-draggable"
        data-reactid=".r[2zxee]"
        id="messi"
        onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
        className="my-draggable"
      >
        Drag Me! See how children are passed through to the div!
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Draggable initialPos={{ x: 50, y: 20 }} />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
.my-draggable {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #cca;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

If you want to pass in children, you can do that too with this modified version: https://jsfiddle.net/hceLjz90/

```js
class Draggable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pos: props.initialPos || {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      },
      dragging: false,
      rel: null
    }

    this.onMouseMove = this.onMouseMove.bind(this);
    this.onMouseDown = this.onMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.onMouseUp = this.onMouseUp.bind(this);
  }

  // calculate relative position to the mouse and set dragging=true
  onMouseDown(e) {
    if (e.button !== 0) return
    const de = document.documentElement;
    const box = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getBoundingClientRect();
    const top = box.top + window.pageYOffset - de.clientTop;
    const left = box.left + window.pageXOffset - de.clientLeft;
    this.setState({
      dragging: true,
      rel: {
        x: e.pageX - left,
        y: e.pageY - top,
      }
    })
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  onMouseUp(e) {
    this.setState({
      dragging: false
    })
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  onMouseMove(e) {
    if (!this.state.dragging) return
    this.setState({
      pos: {
        x: e.pageX - this.state.rel.x,
        y: e.pageY - this.state.rel.y
      }
    })
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  componentDidUpdate(props, state) {
    if (this.state.dragging && !state.dragging) {
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove)
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp)
    } else if (!this.state.dragging && state.dragging) {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove)
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return ( <div
      style={{
            position: "absolute",
            left: this.state.pos.x,
            top: this.state.pos.y,
            border: "2px solid rgb(170, 170, 85)",
            padding: "10px"
        }}
        className="my-draggable"
        data-reactid=".r[2zxee]"
        id="messi"
        onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
        className="my-draggable"
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Draggable initialPos={{ x: 50, y: 20 }}>
    <h1>This is a child element</h1>
    <p>This is also a child element</p>
</Draggable>, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```css
.my-draggable {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #cca;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanksss a lotttttt